# SQL | Display all rows where date is not current month

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables
In one table there are my employees and when they changed the Department
In the second table there is my current date

Employee Table

```
+------------------+--------+-------------+-----------------+
| Personal Number  | Salary | Department  | MonthWhenJoined |
+------------------+--------+-------------+-----------------+
|              224 |   1000 | HR          |              03 |
|              224 |   1500 | R&D         |              07 |
|              578 |   1200 | Sales       |              04 |
|              578 |   2000 | Engineering |              09 |
|              694 |   1400 | R&D         |              04 |
|              694 |   1500 | Sales       |              08 |
+------------------+--------+-------------+-----------------+
```

Table with current Date

```
+------------+-----+-------+------+
|    Date    | Day | Month | Year |
+------------+-----+-------+------+
| 01.09.2019 |  01 |    09 | 2019 |
+------------+-----+-------+------+
```

Now I want to only see all Employee that have no 'MonthWhenJoined' equal to the current Month.
So the Result would be something like this

```
+------------------+--------+-------------+-----------------+
| Personal Number  | Salary | Departement | MonthWhenJoined |
+------------------+--------+-------------+-----------------+
|              224 |   1000 | HR          |              03 |
|              224 |   1500 | R&D         |              07 |
|              694 |   1400 | R&D         |              04 |
|              694 |   1500 | Sales       |              08 |
+------------------+--------+-------------+-----------------+
```

I know it can not be that hard, but I cant figure it out …
Thank you for your help!

Comment: Your table with current date has been updated for more than 2 weeks.

Comment: @jarlh haha :) it was just an example

Comment: Still makes sense. I'd never trust a stored current date in a table. Either create a stored procedure or a view returning the actual current date!

Comment: @jarlh, why does the current date in the table have to be the same as the day the query is run?

Comment: @Jodrell, if it is another date _current date_ is very misleading...

Comment: @jarlh, if the table had the same name as some system function then yes, that would be confusing. However, perhaps you can imagine a situation where the current date of the system is different from today.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM Employee
WHERE PersonalNumber NOT IN (
        SELECT PersonaNumber
        FROM Employee
        WHERE MonthWhenJoined =
        SELECT Month
        FROM currentDate
        )
```

Comment: @clem995, [`SELECT *` is generally a bad idea](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3639964/659190), additionally, as a personal preference, I don't like the use of avoidable subqueries but that would not effect the query plan.

Answer (score 2):

in this case I would join two tables putting those dates as different on it

```
SELECT * FROM Employee 
WHERE personalNumber NOT IN 
  (SELECT personalNumber 
   FROM Emplayee e 
   JOIN currentDate d ON e.MonthWhenJoined = d.month)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but then I still get one row of 578
I want dont want to display a person, if he has moved in the current month

Comment: I have edited the answer, i didn´t see that detail of not repeating the employee, try this new one

Comment: @clem995, [`SELECT *` is generally a bad idea](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3639964/659190), additionally, as a personal preference, I don't like the use of avoidable subqueries but that would not effect the query plan.

Answer (score 0):

Simple,

```
SELECT
         E.[Personal Number],
         E.[Salary],
         E.[Department],
         E.[MonthWhenJoined]
   FROM
         [someSchema].[Employee] E
      LEFT JOIN
         [someSchema].[CurrentDate] C
            ON C.[Month] = E.[MonthWhenJoined]
   WHERE
         C.[Date] IS NULL;
```

of course, there is no way to tell if that month was in the same year as the current date.

Answer (score 0):

Simple:

```
SELECT * FROM employee WHERE `MonthWhenJoined` NOT IN(SELECT `Month` FROM date WHERE    `Year` = YEAR(CURDATE()));
```

Comment: @clem995, [`SELECT *` is generally a bad idea](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3639964/659190), additionally, as a personal preference, I don't like the use of avoidable subqueries but that would not effect the query plan.